# Wrong upload path in Django

Tags: django, nginx, django-3.0

I have configured Django3.0 / Ubuntu 18 / NginX Media root in URL.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and in Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name XXXXX.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/user/proj;
    }
    location /media/ {
        root /home/user/proj;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/proj_gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

and in models, I have some FileField and ImageField with 'upload_to ' attribute. When I upload something through admin, everything is okay and files will be uploaded in sub-folders `(eg. media/2020/avatar/1.jpg)` but when I do that through forms, files will be uploaded in right sub-directories but the image (or file) URL shows the root of media `(eg. media/1.jpg)` and when I click on URL, it returns 404. I can not figure out why this is happening, I've used this config in dozens of web sites and they work like a charm.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You say that image is in folder `media/2020/avatar/1.jpg` and your url is `media/1.jpg` which seems odd as nginx will try to find it in `media` folder and not the subfolder created. You should give urls like `media/2020/avatar/1.jpg` in your html.

Comment: Yes, this is odd. The URL just shows the media root. everything is ok. even if I upload the file or image through admin, The URL in the template is right!